# Verifique se o controlador tem um construtor público sem parâmetros

Tags: c#, visual-studio, injeção-de-dependência, solid, ioc

Alguém me ajuda, estou criando um projeto e na parte de injeção de dependência estou tendo o seguinte erro quando faço uma requisição do Postman na minha Api: Ocorreu um erro ao tentar criar um controlador do tipo 'PessoaController'. Verifique se o controlador tem um construtor público sem parâmetros.

Minha classe do simple injector:

```
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Domain.Interfaces.Entities;
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Domain.Entities;
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Domain.Interfaces;
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Context;
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using SimpleInjector;

namespace MonitoramentoEscolar.Api.App_Start {
    public class SimpleInjectorRegistrar {
        public static Container Registrar() {
            var container = new Container();
            container.RegisterSingleton<MonitoramentoEscolarDbContext>();
            container.Register<IPessoaEntity, PessoaEntity>();
            container.Register<IPessoaTipoEntity, PessoaTipoEntity>();
            container.Register<IPessoaRepository, PessoaRepository>();
            container.Verify();
            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

Meu controller, se eu criar um construtor vazio sem parâmetros ele inicializa somente o construtor vazio e quando chega no Endpoint da erro de NullReference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace MonitoramentoEscolar.Api.Controllers {

    public class PessoaController : ApiController {

        public readonly IPessoaRepository pessoaRepository;
        public readonly IPessoaTipoRepository pessoaTipoRepository;

        public PessoaController(IPessoaRepository pessoaRepository, IPessoaTipoRepository pessoaTipoRepository) {
            this.pessoaRepository = pessoaRepository;
            this.pessoaTipoRepository = pessoaTipoRepository;
        }
        public PessoaController() {

        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Pessoa/GetAll")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
            var pessoas = pessoaRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            if (pessoas == null)
                return BadRequest("Nenhum dado foi encontrado");
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, pessoas);
        }
```

A classe SimpleInjectorRegistrar:

```
using MonitoramentoEscolar.Api.App_Start;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MonitoramentoEscolar.Api {
    public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(SimpleInjectorRegistrar.Registrar());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém me ajuda e se possível me explica o pq estou passando por isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Onde a classe SimpleInjectorRegistrar é chamada? Qual o framework? .Net Core? .Net Full Framework?

Comment: As suas entidades possuem um construtor sem parâmetros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser uma das seguintes opcoes:

- O seu service faz uso de outras interfaces que nao foram injetadas
- O seu service nao tem construtor

Mais:

- o seu metodo de injection esta errado `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));`
  https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html

e por ultimo vc nao precisa criar construtor vazio em um controller

```
 public PessoaController() {

        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui resolver o problema, faltou eu adicionar no Nuget o SimpleInjector WebApi, registrar uma interface que faltava e passei a receber no metodo Registrar um HttpConfiguration, ficou assim: public static void Registrar(HttpConfiguration config) e utilizei mais essas duas linhas de codigo:  container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config); depois do Verify(); usei está tb:
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);